# XML envelope namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

What is correct URI of XML envelope namespace. I have seen many of them, e.g. "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2001/06/soap-envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/". Please tell me that which URI should be used and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much covered in those comments at the top of each file.

2003/05 states: "Schema defined in the SOAP Version 1.2 Part 1 specification Recommendation"

xmlsoap.org has their own version "modifications to the W3C files"

So use the latest from w3c ("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope").

You will know when you need to use a different one.